# proq sql for merging two tables by a column

Tags: sql, sas

I have two tables:

data1:

```
 obs unique_id date     v1  x1  x2  x3  x4
    1   4   20050203    A   1   2   3   4
    2   3   20050203    B   2   3   4   5
    3   2   20050203    C   3   4   5   6
    4   1   20050203    D   4   5   6   7
```

data2:

```
unique_id   z1  z2  c1  c2
1               
2               
3               
4
```

My question is:
I would like to find a new variable,say,p1=((x1+x3)-z1)/z2) by matching the unique_id. For eg., matching unique_id 1 with 1 from both table and then calculating the variable.Please help me with a proq sql for this.

Comment: Why is data2 table empty? If it is empty where would the values of z1 and z2 come from? Please show an example of result set you want

Comment: Sorry, I din't put the values. It has numerical values similar to x1 and all.

Answer (score 0):

This simply should have join

```
SELECT ((x1+x3)-z1)/z2) AS p1
 FROM data1,data2
 WHERE data1.unique_id=data2.unique_id;
```

Comment: Thanks but what if I have all these columns in one dataset data1?

Comment: Then simply, SELECT ((x1+x3)-z1)/z2) AS p1 FROM data1

Answer (score 0):

using `join` operator:

```
select ((x1+x3)-z1)/z2) as p1
from data1 d1 inner join data2 d2 
   on d1.unique_id = d2.unique_id
```

In case you have no matching data in data2 you can utilize `Left outer join` and `COALESCE` for example:

```
select ((x1+x3)-COALESCE(z1,0))/Coalesce(z2,1)) as p1
from data1 d1 left outer join data2 d2 
    on d1.unique_id = d2.unique_id
```